# problem with displaying graph points in MPAndroidChart

Tags: java, android-studio

I use MPAndroidChart to draw geometric shapes and for some reason some points that belong to a circle are not drawn. what could this be related to?

```
        ArrayList<ILineDataSet> dataSets = new ArrayList();
        for (int i = 0; i < fig.size(); i++) {
                LineDataSet dataset = new LineDataSet(get_Datas(fig.get(i)), "");
                dataSets.add(dataset);
        }
        LineData data = new LineData(dataSets);
        chart.setData(data);
        System.out.println(chart.getData().getEntryCount());
        chart.invalidate();
    }
```

the part of the code where I get the points for the circle:

```
double x0 = ((Circle) iShape).getP().GetX(0);
            double y0 = ((Circle) iShape).getP().GetX(1);
            double r = ((Circle) iShape).getR();
            double i = 0;
            while (i < 2 * Math.PI) {
                entries.add(new Entry((float) (x0 + r * Math.cos(i)), (float) (y0 + r * Math.sin(i))));
                i += 0.1;
            }
            entries.add(new Entry((float) (x0 + r * Math.cos(0)), (float) (y0 + r * Math.sin(0))));
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zQOPw.png)

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my own question, for the future: in MPAndroidChart, the coordinates should be sorted by X